# How to create .repo file?

Tags: package-management, yum, packages, repository

I am trying to create my RPM repository, besides the posts on SuperUser I have followed the [usage document of createRepo](http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/RepoCreate), which was pretty straight forward.

Although, regarding the .repo file I couldn't find any detailed tutorial. 
What I am exactly interested in, is all available sections or tags ( such as `enabled` or `autorefresh`) in the file and What they actually do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the manual pages, the yum.conf file is the main configuration file with additional configuration files being read from the directories set by the reposdir option (default is `/etc/yum/repos.d`). Therefore, for a complete list of repository section entries, refer to `man yum.conf`.

Comment: the man page does not list `autorefresh` (fully updated Centos Linux 7.3.1611)

Comment: @audfhg That is correct. Currently, the RHEL5, RHEL6, and RHEL7 yum man pages do not mention an `autorefresh` option.